# How do I see container health status for containers from my docker-compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, go-templates

Since docker-compose 1.10.0 [there is support for health checks](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/tag/1.10.0). I started implementing those in one of my docker-compose files.

There are a couple sites where it is suggested that health status of a container can be seen from `docker ps`. See below.

However, I don't see any health status when running `docker ps`. An excerpt of my docker-compose file looks like:

```
version: "2.1"

services:

  my-service:
    container_name: my-service
    image: "our-registry:5000/my-service:1.0.1"
    expose: [3000]
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - other-service-1
      - other-service-2
    healthcheck:
      test: ["nc", "-z", "127.0.0.1", "3000", "||", "exit", "1"]
      interval: "2s"
      timeout: "1
```

An excerpt of my `docker ps` output looks like:

```
# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS          NAMES
af680b9fc6c3        our-registry/pr-georegion:1.0.1        "node index.js"          8 minutes ago       Up 8 minutes        3000/tcp       pr-georegion
```

Docker and docker-compose versions:

```
# docker -v
Docker version 1.12.6, build 78d1802
# docker-compose -v
docker-compose version 1.10.1, build b252738
```

[Example 1](https://github.com/tomwillfixit/healthcheck/commit/8268e53ef36aa5ebc895fc83b55c18bc7618c460)

[image: Example 1]

[Example 2](https://blog.couchbase.com/2016/november/docker-health-check-keeping-containers-healthy)

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the problem in my docker-compose file. From the [official docs](test must be either a string or a list. If it’s a list, the first item must be either NONE, CMD or CMD-SHELL. If it’s a string, it’s equivalent to specifying CMD-SHELL followed by that string.):

> test must be either a string or a list. If it’s a list, the first item must be either NONE, CMD or CMD-SHELL. If it’s a string, it’s equivalent to specifying CMD-SHELL followed by that string.

So I changed:

```
test: ["nc", "-z", "127.0.0.1", "3000", "||", "exit", "1"]
```

for:

```
test: ["CMD-SHELL", "nc -z 127.0.0.1 3000 || exit 1"]
```

Comment: The `|| exit 1` is superfluous. nc's exit code is already non-zero if the port is not open.

Comment: You're right that it is superfluous. I don't remember anymore for what reason I wanted to add `|| exit 1` but I'll leave the question and the answer because it can still be interesting to know how to let a shell interpret the command (pipes, or's, and's, etc.)